# Wind blowing on String

Tags: java, string, split, tokenize

I have some basic idea on how to do this task, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. So we have class WindyString with metod blow. After using it :

```
System.out.println(WindyString.blow(
    "Abrakadabra!          The    second  chance to pass has already BEGUN! "));
```

we should obtain something like this :

```
                    e              a  e         a           a  ea y
   br k d br !    Th    s c nd   ch nc    t    p ss   h s    lr  d    B G N!
  A  a a a  a            e o               o           a               E U
```

so in a nutshell in every second word we pick every vowels and move them one line above. In the second half of words we move vowels one line below.

I know I should split string to tokens with tokenizer or split method,but what next ? Create 3 arrays each representing each row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use regex. This should be instructive:

```
static String blow(String s) {
    String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
    String middle = s.replaceAll("[" + vowels + "]", " ");
    int flip = 0;
    String[] side = { "", "" };
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    for (String word; (word = sc.findInLine("\\s*\\S*")) != null; ) {
        side[flip] += word.replaceAll(".", " ");
        side[1-flip] += word.replaceAll("[^" + vowels + "]", " ");
        flip = 1-flip;
    }
    return String.format("|%s|%n|%s|%n|%s|", side[0], middle, side[1]);
}
```

I added the `|` characters in the output to show that this processes excess whitespaces correctly -- all three lines are guaranteed the same length, taking care of leading blanks, trailing blanks, or even ALL blanks input.

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, this is definitely a good one to start learning with.

The `middle` is simply the original string with all vowels replaced with spaces.

Then, `side[0]` and `side[1]` are the top and bottom lines respectively. We use the `Scanner` to extract every word (preserving leading and trailing spaces). The way we process each word is that in one side, everything is replaced by blanks; in the other, only non-vowels are replaced by blanks. We flip sides with every word we process.

Comment: can you lead me through this regex ?

Comment: Regexes can be very tricky, but I'm only using basic elements here. Read tutorials, specifically regarding: character class `[`...`]` and the `\s` and `\S` shorthands, negation `^`, the dot metacharacter `.`, and repetition `*`. Don't be discouraged: regex is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's probably an easy (not very performant) way to solve the problem.

Create 3 arrays; one is filled with the actual data and 2 arrays are filled (`Arrays.fill`) with `' '`.

Then iterate over the array containing the actual data, and keep an integer of which word you're currently at and a boolean if you already matched whitespace.

While iterating, you check if the character is a vowel or not. If it's a vowel, check the word-count (oddness/evenness) and place it in the first or third array.
When you reach a whitespace, set the boolean and increase the word count. If you reach another whitespace, check whether the whitespace is already set: if so, continue. If you match a non-whitespace, reset the whitespace boolean.

Then join all arrays together and append a new-line character between each joined array and return the string.